# Common code to execute after execution of step definition in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

Is there way to execute common code after execution of each and every step definition in cucumber feature file ? That code will verify to move forward for execution of further steps or not.

Comment: If u are on cucumber-jvm 3, then u can look at AfterStep annotation. Which version  and which language?

Comment: There are various hooks that should work with a variety of versions of cucumber. Around hooks in Ruby, BeforeStep and AfterStep in Cucumber JVM and CucumberJS (if you go back a few versions). If you provided a code example, we might be able to help you more to achieve what you want